# How to make a solid horizontal line from start to end with css

Tags: css, line

I'm working on an assignment from cs50 web course and need to make sort of a google advanced search page. I can't make it why I have spaces (right and left) when "drawing" the line and the original google page doesn't. How to make a line from start to end?

[image]
[image]

My code is:

- html

```
<div class="line"></div>
```

- css

```
.line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
```

Comment: Probably you have some margins or padding somewhere

Comment: The spaces are almost certainly due to margin/padding on a parent element, we can't say exactly with the example here.

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you. Please include a runnable snippet which shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you guys, will try to figure it out‍♀️